# Why does console.log return an array when passed a template literal?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For some methods, modern JS allows template literals to be passed without using parens.

ie [1,2,3].join`+` //=> '1+2+3'

`console.log`, however, returns something unexpected.

console.log`hello,world` //=> ["hello,world", raw: Array(1)]

Why is an array returned here as the output of console.log?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals - See "tagged template literals"

Comment: Thanks -- any idea why returning an array is the preferred behavior for console.log?

Comment: Not exactly sure, I can't seem to reproduce your result exactly. An array is being returned because tagged template literals are passed as arrays to the function, and I guess all template literals have the `raw` property indicating the raw string.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're working with [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The backtick stuff doesn't mean you can eschew parens willy-nilly.